# How to change folder permissions inside a docker container using docker compose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using nodejs and a custom nginx docker image https://github.com/bunkerity/bunkerized-nginx for my application using docker compose.

Nginx image has the automatic letsencrypt support and we can bind mount a folder to store the key files.However for security reasons it runs as an unprivileged user with UID/GID 101 and getting a permission error for the /etc/letsencrypt directorry.

I searched through the source code and found the following lines that causing this error

#### Condition that docker image checks

```
# /etc/letsencrypt
if [ ! -w "/etc/letsencrypt" ] || [ ! -r "/etc/letsencrypt" ] || [ ! -x "/etc/letsencrypt" ] ; then
    echo "[!] ERROR - wrong permissions on /etc/letsencrypt"
    exit 1
fi
```

What I want is now to set owner of the above directory as root or give the 777 permissions using the docker compose/Docker file.

#### My Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  bunkerized_nginx:
    image: bunkerity/bunkerized-nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - express-app
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 443:8443

    volumes:
      - ./nginx-bunkerized/:/etc/letsencrypt:rw
    
    #command:
      #- chown root:root /etc/letsencrypt
      #- chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=www.dasun123.ml
      - USE_REVERSE_PROXY=yes
      - REVERSE_PROXY_URL=/
      - AUTO_LETS_ENCRYPT=yes
      - REDIRECT_HTTP_TO_HTTPS=yes
      - REVERSE_PROXY_HOST=http://express-app:3000

  express-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
```

Comment: What about `command: chown root:root /etc/letsencrypt && chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt`

Comment: Nope its not working.I think the image is overriding it or something like that.

Comment: Also you could try setting the entrypoint like this: `entrypoint: chown root:root /etc/letsencrypt && chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt && /opt/entrypoint/entrypoint.sh`, it has precedence. Or you can create your own image, using a Dockerfile and modify the folder permissions in it.

Comment: I'll try.Thank you